SQL Server import data creates wrong values
I got a random excel spreadsheet that needs to be loaded into a SQL Server table.
The problem occurs in both scenarios - if I create a table myself or if I let SSMS Export task create it for me on the fly.
The spreadsheet has a few columns - A, B, C... E, F. The data in the column 'C' can look something like this:
34343
140990140
140990140
141021668
 2024-TMFALM-PLAN
 dda3435ddd
 M00960380 
(2024-TMFALM-003680-PLAN)-2024-TMFALM-003065-AMND

(Please, do note that there can be trailing spaces in some rows, I can't control that. Also, this field can be blank)
The data gets imported fine, but the columns that had pure numbers are imported as is, but the others - got imported as NULLS.
I am breaking my head trying to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

ACE infers data types and when you have mixed values like this it can infer incorrectly. If you format the values as text in the spreadsheet that could help. Otherwise you're better off using something else, such as a CSV.

Thanks, I did format the values as text in excel spreadsheet.  It does not help.  I even trimmed the trailing and leading spaces.  Did not help.
Problem using csv is that there are other columns with text that can contain commas (,) and I can't escape it

Excel has the option to use a delimiter other than a comma.  For example, you can have a pipe (|) delimited file.

And you can specify the delimiter in the SSMS import wizard, I think?

Have you tried to turn off type guessing in the ACE driver's connection string? i.e.: in the connection string's Extended Properties include IMEX=1.

Yeah, this is one of the reasons i wrote my own client, importing excel files, it's unbelievably bad in SSMS. Another fun thing is if row 20000 is very long and you forget to fix correct varchar lengths. One trick i remember working is to import headers as part of the rows, this way the first row will always be text which shouldn't mess things up, then you just need to remove it after it's imported. Alternative to add a dummy row after the header which is later removed. Btw, "format values as text" is not correct, you need to add an apostrophe to every row to force them to be text

Thank you all.
I ended up going with the regular .csv file, with adjustments of removing textual commas from the column values to not interfere with the separator.  And also, trimming leading and trailing spaces in the columns where i spotted them.
I also removed any formatting in excel before saving it as .csv file and then updated the default data types that SSMS suggest when running the import task.
